# How to remove overlapping of rectangle boundaries in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, overlap, rectangles, boundary

I have to draw a rectangle of 30*30 on an image of different colors. I am able to draw the rectangle of different colors as per the requirement but the boundaries are getting overlapped thus mixing of color is happening. I am unable to put any bounds so that the boundaries don't overlap and each rectangle can be seen clearly. I will be thankful for the help.

```
import cv2
from scipy import misc
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# read image
img = misc.imread("img.tif")

csv = np.loadtxt("classes.csv" , dtype = str ,delimiter = ',')

color = np.loadtxt("colorlist1.csv" , dtype = str ,delimiter = ',')

row =0

for i in range(csv.shape[0]):
  col=0
  for j in range(csv.shape[1]):
     #print row, row+30
     #print col,col+30
     clr = int(csv[i][j])
     cv2.rectangle(img,(col,row),(col+30,row+30),(int(color[clr][0]),int(color[clr][1]),int(color[clr][2])),4,2)
     col = col+30
  row = row+30
print "************"


plt.imsave("img_crop_rect.tif",img)
print "Done"
```

[image: Image with overlapped rectangular boundary]

But I want rectangles like this.
[image]

Comment: Would `col=col+31` and `row=row+31` solve your problem and still satisfy your requirement?

Comment: No, it will not, as it will move the patch one coordinate forward and will disort the object distribution. I need something which can dissolve the boundary littlebit so that each patch can be seen distinct.

Comment: What do you mean by 'each patch can be seen distinct'? The rectangles are overlapping anyway.

Comment: Dear Pyan please see the new figure added where no boundary overlapping is there. I want the same thing.

Comment: Why not just make each rectangle a little smaller in this case? `cv2.rectangle(img,(col,row),(col+28,row+28),(int(color[clr][0]),int(color[clr][1]),int(color[clr][2])),4,2)
     col = col+30`

Comment: Thanks a Lot. I think sometime we do lot of stupid things that we cant even think of basics and commonsense.